# PHP session value defined in one file, is undefined in another file

Tags: php, session

I have 2 php files, in the first file:

```
    <?php
        session_start();    
.
.
.
        $_SESSION['favcolor'] = "green";
        echo "ses: ".$_SESSION['favcolor'];
    ?>
```

and in the second file:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "ses: ".$_SESSION['favcolor'];
?>
```

When executing the first page, i do see the correct favcolor but when executing the second page in the same browser, I get {"error":"Undefined index: favcolor"}. I know I need to check the existence of this key before using it but I was wondering why it's not there in the first place because this is what I want to achieve, the store/restore a session value between PHP calls. What am I missing?

Comment: Sure that there's no output before `$_SESSION['favcolor'] = "green";`?

Comment: This is an interesting issue. I suggest three debugging things: 1) Echo your session id `session_id();` Not sure wether it returns or echo it. 2) Open file1 via browser, delete `$_SESSION['favcolor'] = "green";` and open file1 again. 3) Check if there is a function like "isSessionStarted" and add it in both files.

Comment: 1. echoing the session id in both files, I get 2 different ids. 2. how to delete the $_SESSION['favcolor'] = "green"? not sure I understand. 3. I don't have isSessionStarted but if I have session ID, I guess it is started?

Comment: u-mulder, what do you mean by sure there's no output before $_SESSION['favcolor'] = "green";? the first output is after setting this value, now I added the session id just before that

Comment: Turn on error reporting and display errors on screen: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always when developing and testing code, placed at the very _top_ of both scripts. The whitespace before `<?php` in the first file is very suspicious, and possibly indicative of [the Headers already sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) error, which would prevent a session from being initialized properly.

Comment: It could possibly be a http:// versus https:// thing, so make sure you are using the same protocol when accessing both pages. (Normally you would get the same session ID, but I think that can be configured to work differently.)

Comment: I added error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); but nothing new showed up. while working in the same tab (f5), it does show the same session id but the session id is different between the 2 tabs. If I take the URL from tab2 and run it in tab1, the session id is of tab2.

Comment: The problem was that on tab1 i did domain.com/page1.php.... and on the other tab it was www.domain.com/page2.php.... the www difference caused the problem...